# Remove from Recycler View with outside

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Android. My Application is utilizing Recycler View and the firebase sends the triggering update to add, edit delete the checkbox in Recycler view.

The interactor gets the triggered update from the server which then calls the addItem,UpdateItem or RemoveItem method in adapter through presenter.

I can add, update fine in Recycler View but when I am trying to remove the item from the Recycler view I am having difficult time in getting position of adapter.

Through Iterating, I can figure out the index of ArrayList but I don't know how to get position of the view to remove it.

The below code in removeItem method removes the required view perfectly fine but also duplicate(add) the last view again.
What I need is to remove the whole view without adding the duplicate last view.  I don't know how to get `getadapterPosition()`, Since I am not dealing with local triggers like onClick.

```
public class CustomShoppingRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomShoppingRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements ShoppingAdapterView {
private final ArrayList<Shopping> mMessageList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
    vh= new ViewHolder(v);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Shopping current = mMessageList.get(position);

    holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.setTag(current.getItem());
    holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.setText(current.getItem());
    holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.setChecked(current.getItemStatus());
    holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.setOnClickListener(null);

    holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    current.setItemStatus(holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.isChecked());
                    presenter.updateItemToServer(current);
              tag=  (String) holder.mShoppingItemCheckBox.getTag();
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void removeItem(Shopping shopping) {
    Integer index = 0;

    for (Shopping _item : mMessageList) {
        index = mMessageList.indexOf(_item);

        if (_item.getItem().equals(shopping.getItem())) {
                if (index != -1) {
                    mMessageList.remove(index);
                    notifyItemRemoved(index);
                }
        }
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CheckBox mShoppingItemCheckBox;
    private TextView mMessageTextView;

     ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_author);
        mShoppingItemCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopping_item);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use iterator and remove by iterator.remove() ?

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear. I need to remove the view based on the item I remove from the arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the Iterator it solved my problem.

```
    Integer index = 0;
    Iterator<Shopping> it = mMessageList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {

        if (it.next().getItem().equals(shopping.getItem())) {
            it.remove();
            notifyItemRemoved(index);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(index, mMessageList.size());
            // If you know it's unique, you could `break;` here
        }
        index=index+1;
    }
```

Thanks  Tomasz Czura  for the answer.